# AngularJS UI-Router reloadOnSearch not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a view where it is possible to have different objects loaded based on an ID. It is a get request and the controller or state should not entirely reload. I am using ui-router and I've come across the "reloadOnSearch" property. Setting this to false should not reload the controller based on the params, it should only reload on state change. However this is not working. Here is my config function:

```
var MAIN_CONFIGURATION = {
Setup: function(app) {
    app.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state("myState",
            {
                url: "/mystate/:id",
                reloadOnSearch: false,
                templateUrl: "/app/Main/templates/test.html?version=0.0.0.0001",
                controller: testCtrl
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.when("", ["$state", function($state) {
            $state.go("myState");
        }]);
    }]);
    .
    .
    .
    }
};
```

Below is my partial HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items" ui-sref="myState({id: '{{item.ID}}'})">
                <td>{{item.FirstName}}</td>
                <td>{{item.LastName}}</td>
            </tr>
```

Basically a bunch of table rows are generated and when a row is clicked on, I am expecting the controller to not entirely reload. However, it does. Even when pressing the back and forward buttons on the browser, it is being reloaded.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I just figured it out. The route must contain "query" parameters. Thus I cannot use "/mystate/:id". I should instead use "/mystate?id".